Expected distance before revisiting any point of random walk on an infinite hexagonal grid
I don't understand how to combine knowledge that one loop will be in 6 meters and expected value calculation. Like should I just multiply each step in meters by 0.5 as it's the probability of each.
Kindly give me some materials I can read or watch so I could at least understand in which way I should go.
Here's the statement of the problem:
Max runs on a geometric plane. He starts at some point and runs in some direction for 1 meter. After that, he turns 120 degrees in one of two directions, from which he chooses equally likely. Then he runs in this direction for 1 meter and turns 120 degrees again at random in one of two directions, etc.
Let T be how many meters Max runs before he ends up at a point in the plane he has already been in.
Find the expected value of T.
hexagonal grid

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Intuitively, you realize that the expected number of steps should not be too high since Mark rotates his direction vector by 120 degrees every step so he can't really go very far without intersecting! In the best case scenario, he reaches his original position in 3 steps, hence the expected value must be greater than 3 since there are other paths as well.
Note that expected value of T means the probability of the specific path multiplied by the length of the path. Say his starting point is A and Step $1$ is chosen in any direction, say right, reaching B. Now the next two possible positions are defined. From each of these positions, you can reach A. If you draw this out, you see a pattern and the expected value $$E[T] = \frac{3}{2^2} + \frac{3}{2^2} + \frac{4}{2^3} + \frac{4}{2^3} \cdots = 4$$ which also makes sense intuitively.

Thanks a lot for your answer! But I don't get how's the best case scenario is 3 steps? As far as I understand Mark cannot go backwards and 1 'circle' should be at least 6 edges. I added a picture to the question, so we were on the same page.

As far as turning 120 degrees is concerned, it means flipping the original direction and then choosing any direction and turning 60 degrees. What the picture describes is a hexagonal grid which should be termed as turning 60 degrees.
